# Best way to select max value of each group on top of other query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Does someone know how to select max value of each group on top of other query?

Example table:

```
Class    Exam    Grade
Math1    Mid       1
Math2    Mid       2 
Math1    Final     1
```

Say I have the first query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Class = 'Math1'
```

Now using the resulting table I want to group by Exam and keep only the row with the max grade:

```
SELECT view1.* 
FROM
 (SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE Class = 'Math1') AS view1, view2
WHERE view1.Exam = view2.Exam
AND  view1.Grade > view2.Grade
```

The problem I can't give 2 alias for the same table. So view1 and view2 wont work the way is written. Is there a best practice?
Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
Thank you all for the answers, it helped me but I was trying to remember the following solution with the WITH:

```
WITH view AS (SELECT *
                 FROM table
                 WHERE Class = 'Math1)
SELECT view1.*
FROM view view1, view view2
WHERE view1.Exam = view2.Exam
AND  view1.Grade > view2.Grade
```

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
SELECT distinct max(grade) over (partition by exam), exam
  FROM table
  WHERE Class = 'Math1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row with the highest grade, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Class = 'Math1' 
ORDER BY grade DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` to select the row with the highest grade per exam for all `Math` classes

```
select * from (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by exam, Class order by grade desc) rn
    where Class = 'Math1'
) t where rn = 1
```

If you want to include ties for the highest grade then use `rank` instead of `row_number`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`distinct on`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) to select row with max grade for each exam:

```
select distinct on (exam) exam,
    t.*
from (
    -- Your query here
    select *
    from table
    where class = 'Math1'
    ) t
order by exam,
    grade desc;
```

Or directly:

```
select distinct on (exam) exam,
    t.*
from table
where class = 'Math1'
order by exam,
    grade desc;
```